# Pandas Dataframe Pivot-table: How to group by column values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe structure:

```
   dimension  month of year    metric1      metric2
0     A          201809          xxxx         xxxx
1     B          201809          xxx          xxx
2     C          201808          xxx          xxx
...
```

Next I created a pivot table:

`table = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['metric1', 'metric2'], index=['dimension'], columns=['ga:yearMonth'], aggfunc=np.sum)`

which resulted in:

```
                       metric1                    metric2
month of year    201807 201808 201809      201807 201808 201809 
dimension
A                   x      x      x          x      x      x
B                   x      x      x          x      x      x
C                   x      x      x          x      x      x
```

This is very close to what I want, except I want to have the numbers grouped by the month of year, rather than the metric. Something like this:

```
month of year     201807    201808     201809 
metric            1   2     1   2      1   2
dimension
A                 x   x     x   x      x   x
B                 x   x     x   x      x   x
C                 x   x     x   x      x   x
```

From looking around, my understanding is that this will require using MultiIndexing, although I've been having trouble getting a working solution.

Comment: If your columns values and index values are in the wrong order...did you try swapping them?

Comment: Check with swaplevel

Comment: `table.swaplevel(0,1, axis=1)`

Comment: @G.Anderson this does not work. I still want the values themselves to be metric1&metric2, swapping columns/index will result in displaying the wrong data

Comment: @user3483203 the swap did not end up grouping `month of year`, so the result was the same structure

Answer (score 1):

i just made up some values for metric1 and metric2. but see code below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([['A', '201809' ,234, 567],
                  ['B', '201809' ,105, 640],
                  ['C', '201808' ,250, 700],
                  ['A', '201808' ,200, 267],
                  ['B', '201809' ,57, 654],
                  ['C', '201807' ,205, 620],
                  ['A', '201807' ,234, 567],
                  ['B', '201808' ,110, 640],
                  ['C', '201808' ,275, 700],
                  ['A', '201807' ,150, 267],
                  ['B', '201807' ,57, 654],
                  ['C', '201809' ,205, 620]
                 ], columns=['dimension','month','metric1','metric2'])

df2 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['dimension', 'month'], value_vars=['metric1', 'metric2'])

pd.pivot_table(df2, values=['value'], index=['dimension'], columns=['month', 'variable'], aggfunc=np.sum)
```